# Active State Perl - IOCP

Tags: perl, mod-perl, perl-module, mod-perl2

I am thinking to use IOCP in perl in one of our network related code. Currently Active State Perl till 5.10 doesn't offer this feature? Is anyone aware of free module to use ASIO feature like IOCP in perl?

-Karthik

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a module for that, but it should be doable to write such a module even without hacking C using [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::API).

Comment: That's right. Since the network code which I wanted to plug in the IOCP feature already relies on perl socket functions, it might not helpful using Win32::API ( since you need to derive native socket handler out of perl socket handle ). I am thinking to introduce IOCP inside perl source code so I will be able to work on socket handles from perl data structure.